# Efficient way to compute unique values using a PostgreSQL GIN index

Tags: postgresql, json

Say I have a JSONB column, with a GIN index on it.

I can use `jsonb_object_keys()` to fetch the keys for each row. But is there an efficient way of getting the *unique* set of keys, across all rows?

Surely the GIN index must have this information already, right?

NB: I know the "classic" solution: split the single column into a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Are you looking for only top-level keys in the JSONB, or all keys?

Comment: @jjanes I only need the top-level keys.

Comment: how many rows do you have, how often are they changing (new top level keys added, or old removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done.  Of the two built-in GIN operators for indexing JSONB, one of them only stores hashed values, so you wouldn't be able to reverse them, and other one stores flattened keys, irrespective of what level of the JSONB they were at.  That second one also hashes the values if they exceed a certain length.

Both of the methods can lead to false positives, so both rely on "rechecking" the full JSONB in the tabe to make sure they meet the criteria.

For example, with the "jsonb_ops" operator, the value {"ABCD": {"EFGH": "IJKL"}} will initially match the query `@> '{"EFGH":{}}'`, because the value does have "EFGH" as a key.  It would then fail the recheck, because that key occurs at the wrong depth.

Comment: Thanks! Helpful to know not to bark at this tree anymore. :)